# Integrating GIS platform with ESRI system

Tags: django, leaflet, geoserver, esri

I am currently working on a start up that involves the integration of a custom GIS platform with an existing ESRI system. Our platform is built using GeoServer postgres for geospatial data management, Leaflet for map interaction on the frontend, and a Python-based backend (likely Django).I want to know if the integration of open source platform  with the current ESRI enterprise system achievable or no.

Response on if the possibility of the integration of open source platform  with the the ESRI enterprise.

Comment: I’m afraid you’ll have to engage the GIS community, and probably its members that are employed by Esri, to get a definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a state of the art open standard conforming system. Provided you can convince the arch monopolists ESRI to make use of OGC standards such as WMS, WFS & WCS you will have no problems. You might even be able to use the latest OGC features API (so called WFS v3) eventually.